ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with Bounds Check
I am trying to make a fuzzy select tool for an image editing application and have run into an odd problem. It is giving me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, at index -1, while x is 0, (it has 1 subtracted from it in the array), I have checks to see if its in bounds: if(x > 0 &! grid[x - 1][y] ... ) and it still throws the exception. I'm sure it's right in front of my face but I can't see what I'm doing wrong anyway. Here is the SSCCE:
package tests;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FuzzySelectTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1920, 1080, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        boolean grid[][] = new boolean[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];
        int x = 500, y = 500;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        
        if(!(x < 0 ||
                y < 0 || 
                x >= img.getWidth() ||
                y >= img.getHeight())){
            
            ArrayDeque<int[]> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
            queue.add(new int[] {x, y});
            final int imageWidth = img.getWidth(),
                    imageHeight = img.getHeight(),
                    originalColor = img.getRGB(x, y);

            grid[x][y] = true;
            while(!queue.isEmpty()){
                int[] p = queue.poll();
                x = p[0];
                y = p[1];

                System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + grid[x][y]);
                if(x > 0 &! grid[x - 1][y] && img.getRGB(x - 1, y) == originalColor){
                    queue.add(new int[] {--x, y});
                    grid[x][y] = true;
                }
                if(y > 0 &! grid[x][y - 1] && img.getRGB(x, y - 1) == originalColor){
                    queue.add(new int[] {x, --y});
                    grid[x][y] = true;
                }
                if(x + 1 < imageWidth &! grid[x + 1][y] && img.getRGB(x + 1, y) == originalColor){
                    queue.add(new int[] {++x, y});
                    grid[x][y] = true;
                }
                if(y + 1 < imageHeight &! grid[x][y + 1] && img.getRGB(x, y + 1) == originalColor){
                    queue.add(new int[] {x, ++y});
                    grid[x][y] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        for(int yy = 0 ; yy < grid[0].length ; yy++){
            for(int xx = 0 ; xx < grid.length ; xx++){
                if(grid[xx][yy])
                    img.setRGB(xx, yy, Color.white.getRGB());
                else 
                    img.setRGB(xx, yy, Color.black.getRGB());
            }
        }
        
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
}

If this code were correct, it ought to paint out a white rectangle. The fuzzy select algorithm actually works so long as it doesn't have to touch the edge of the BufferedImage.

You need to use the short-circuiting and operator && instead of the single &. The latter evaluates both operands even if the first is false.

Ah, I see. I was under the false impression that &! was like && inversed (and not bitwise). Thank you.

Note that the way the spacing has been applied to &! makes it look like a single operator, but in fact it is two separate operators: a binary & followed by a unary ! that associates with the expression to its right.
